# Finding all special tokens with .NET regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string-formatting

Using a regex, I need to collect ***valid*** top-level tokens `{...}` and ignore token boundaries inside quoted string `"..."` (inluding possible `""`).

Simplified sample:

`TEXT{bbbbb}TEXT{cccc|{dddd}}TEXT{eeee|ff{gg}hh|ii{jj}"kk}{|{}ll""mm{nn}"oo|{pppp}}TEXT`

Expected are 3 matches:

1. `{bbbbb}`
2. `{cccc|{dddd}}`
3. `{eeee|ff{gg}hh|ii{jj}"kk}{|{}ll""mm{nn}"oo|{pppp}}`
   note that content of string `"kk}{|{}ll""mm{nn}"` is ignored

Each token should follow this syntax:

`'{'<tokenName>[a1]['|'[a2|c1]('='|'<>')c2]['|'c3['|'c4]]'}'`

where `aX` is simple regex (`(,-?\d+(:.*)?|:.*)`) and `cX` can contain matched `{`-`}`, plain text and strings `"..."` inside which special characters like `{`,`}`,`|`,`""` are treated as plain text.

I don't understand balancing and escaping which is needed in this regex. Maybe too difficult task for relative beginner.

#### Additional details:

I have done part of the solution and my problem is balancing and quoting.

I'm trying to create extended tokens contained in `input As String` which look similar to [format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/system.string.format%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but also allow conditional evaluation. Using these tokens for example in file name template, users could configure custom parts of file names in batch processing. A token has alphanumeric name and formatting part (including optional condition, true part and false part). Formatting part can be in:

- "Native format" – as known from `String.Format()`, but alphanumeric names instead of placeholders `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}`, ...
  Regex is `(,-?\d+(:.*)?|:.*)`
  .
  Examples:
  `,3`      (converted to standard `{0,3}`)
  `:d`      (converted to standard `{0:d}`)
  `-3:d`    (converted to standard `{0,-3:d}`)
- "Complex format" – either in Native format,
  or with fixed literal `{0}` contextualized as part of string `...{0<native format>}...`
  Regex is: `"("` & nativeFormatSpec & `"|.*({0.*}.*)*)"`
  .
  Examples:
  `-4:d` (only the Native format)
  `prefix {0,-4:d} & once more {0} suffix` is translated to
  . . . .    `String.Format("prefix {0,-4:d} "&}} once" more {0} suffix", value)`

The whole syntax of a valid token now is:

`'{'<tokenName>[quickFormat]['|'[complexFmt1]('='|'<>')value][complexFmt2|[complexFmt3]]'}'`

The code I have uses many named groups, but the regex is probably too simple:

```vb
'*** matching token names (for later use as match.Group(groupName))
Const tokenGroup As String = NameOf(tokenGroup)
Const compareFormatGroup As String = NameOf(compareFormatGroup)
Const quickFormatGroup As String = NameOf(quickFormatGroup)
Const compareOperatorGroup As String = NameOf(compareOperatorGroup)
Const compareValueGroup As String = NameOf(compareValueGroup)
Const defaultFormatGroup As String = NameOf(defaultFormatGroup)
Const elseFormatGroup As String = NameOf(elseFormatGroup)

'*** subpatterns
Const nativeFormatSpec As String = "(,-?\d+(:.*)?|:.*)"
Const complexFormatSpec As String = "(" & nativeFormatSpec & "|.*({0.*}.*)*)" 'value allowing one token {0} multiple times

Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input,
        $"\{{(?<{tokenGroup}>{Regex.Escape(token)})(?<{quickFormatGroup}>{nativeFormatSpec}?)" &
        $"((\|(?<{compareFormatGroup}>{complexFormatSpec}))?(?<{compareOperatorGroup}>=|!=|<>)(?<{compareValueGroup}>.*))?" &
        $"(\|(?<{defaultFormatGroup}>{complexFormatSpec})(\|(?<{elseFormatGroup}>{complexFormatSpec}))?)?\}}")
```

Comment: You're probably better off with a custom parser for this kind of data.

Comment: @Shar1er80 – knowing regexes I knew it is still within their reasonable range, because there were no oddities in the syntax. I just needed help of someone who has more skills in this. The solution shown in the answer is simple and effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your simplified data, here is the regex that should deal with the extraction:

```
\{(?>(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^{}]+)|\{(?<n>)|\}(?<-n>))*(?(n)(?!))\}
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%7B(%3F%3E(%3F%3A%22%5B%5E%22%5D*(%3F%3A%22%22%5B%5E%22%5D*)*%22%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B)%7C%5C%7B(%3F%3Cn%3E)%7C%5C%7D(%3F%3C-n%3E))*(%3F(n)(%3F!))%5C%7D&i=TEXT%7Bbbbbb%7DTEXT%7Bcccc%7C%7Bdddd%7D%7DTEXT%7Beeee%7Cff%7Bgg%7Dhh%7Cii%7Bjj%7D%22kk%7D%7B%7C%7B%7Dll%22%22mm%7Bnn%7D%22oo%7C%7Bpppp%7D%7DTEXT)

[image]

This is basically a balanced braces regex coupled with the VB.NET-like string literal matching regex `"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"`. Note that this part - `(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^{}]+)` - is actually ignored when looking for paired braces (the quoted strings and non-braces).

Comment: Thank you very much & +1. In the sample, I've forgotten functionality for ignoring problematic characters `(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^{}]+)` when in quotes *outside the braces* like `TEXT"}{|}{TEXT"`. Test string is: `TEXT"}{|}{"TEXT{bbbbb}TEXT"}{|}{"TEXT{cccc|{dddd}}TEXT{eeee|ff{gg}hh|ii{jj}"kk}{|{}ll""mm{nn}"oo|{pppp}}TEXT"}{|}{"TEXT` (Expected are the same 3 occurrences as before.)  I was trying to enhance your regex and I can't find how to add abovementioned part ignoring quoted content. May I ask you for additional help? I can also post separate question for it, if you wish.

Comment: [`"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|(\{(?>(?:"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"|[^{}]+)|\{(?<n>)|\}(?<-n>))*(?(n)(?!))\})`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%5b%5e%22%5d*(%3f%3a%22%22%5b%5e%22%5d*)*%22%7c(%5c%7b(%3f%3e(%3f%3a%22%5b%5e%22%5d*(%3f%3a%22%22%5b%5e%22%5d*)*%22%7c%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b)%7c%5c%7b(%3f%3cn%3e)%7c%5c%7d(%3f%3c-n%3e))*(%3f(n)(%3f!))%5c%7d)&i=TEXT%22%7d%7b%7c%7d%7b%22TEXT%7bbbbbb%7dTEXT%22%7d%7b%7c%7d%7b%22TEXT%7bcccc%7c%7bdddd%7d%7dTEXT%7beeee%7cff%7bgg%7dhh%7cii%7bjj%7d%22kk%7d%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8b%7b%7c%7b%7dll%22%22mm%7bnn%7d%22oo%7c%7bpppp%7d%7dTEXT%22%7d%7b%7c%7d%7b%22TEXT). Use `.Groups(1).Value`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning from this. Updated regex actually *matches* added quoted parts instead of *ignoring* them, but well, it is easy to ignore them when programmatically checking matches. Is this approach one of usual ways how this type of problems is effectively solved? (Now I see your edit with `Groups(1).Value`. That answers `:)`)

Comment: Matching and not capturing what you do not need, and matching and *capturing* what you need is a valid regex technique described at [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com).